# Saving Random Forest model to file?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, save, pickle, random-forest

Trying to save Random Forest model.

All the ways fail :

```
self.model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators,criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf=2, max_depth=15,min_samples_split=5, max_features=None, n_jobs=-1, random_state=555)

def save_model(self, fname):
    with open(fname,'wb') as f :
        dill.dumps(self.model, f)



pickle: TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects

joblib : PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod

cPickle : TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects

dill : ValueError: pickle protocol must be <= 2
```

---

```
 : type(r.model)
 : sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier

 :with open('test.dill', 'wb') as f : dill.dump(r.model,f, protocol=2)

  PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'random_forest.RFWords'>: it's not the same object as random_forest.RFWords
```

random_forest.RFWords is the class containing the RF !
 How does it get access to the class which the self.model is inside

---

Hmmm ... I think it is IPython problem ... because now that I'm testing it more thoughtfully ... sometimes it works !!

Probably auto-reloading problem !!

> Yep the moment I modify the source code save_model() stops working ..

Comment: Which ml library are you using ?

Comment: i'm using sklearn.__version__  '0.20.4'

Answer (score 2):

Use joblib to pickle your trained model:

```
from joblib import dump, load
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#load data
X, y = load_data(...)

#fit the model
estimator = RandomForestClassifier()
estimator.fit(X,y)

#pickle model to disk
dump(estimator, 'my_randomforest_model.joblib') 

#loading saved model
estimator = load('my_randomforest_model.joblib')

estimator.predict(...)
```

**Update:**

According to this error you must use a higher protocol for pickeling (>= 2):

> dill : ValueError: pickle protocol must be <= 2

Try to dump with higher protocol as follow:

```
dump(estimator, 'my_randomforest_model.joblib', protocol=2)
```

Comment: same error ? can you provide more details about your model (or pipeline), may be an unpicklable method causes the issue. Try to upgrade to latest version, joblib works fine for me.